# Python, checking a .txt file for a filename

Tags: python

I,m a extreme noobie...

I making a dowsing program.

I have code that randomly picks a image file from a directory. (I can do this)

i need to know how to write the file path of the image to a txt file. (simple database)
Then next time read the txt file to see if that file has been selected in the last 100 entries, if it has been selected, **how to make it go back to the random module and try again until it gets one that has yet to be selected in the 100 times.**

Thanks

sample

```
os.chdir('C:\landscapes\pics')

left1 = random.choice(os.listdir("C:\landscapes\pics"))

# TEST FILE
print(left1)

os.chdir('C:\landscapes')

logfile = open('test.txt', 'r')
loglist = logfile.readlines()
logfile.close()
found = False
for line in loglist:        
    if str(left1) in line:
        print ("Found it")
        found = True

if not found:
    logfile = open('test.txt', 'a')
    logfile.write(str(left1)+"\n")
    logfile.close()
    print ("Not Found!")
```

I,m able to tell if the file is found or not.

I,m just at a loss of what to do next, I think I need kind of While loop?

Comment: Please show the code that you developed, add all necessary data, explain what does not work, and ask a specific question.

Comment: There should be resources and documentation to be able to do this. Have you searched? Please try some code and paste here before asking a generic question.

Comment: This is not a question...!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `while` loop.  Instead, this can be achieved with self referencing methods, which create a sort-of, infinite loop, until a certain condition is met (i.e.: found = False).  Also, I took out the references to `os.chdir` as you don't need those if you specify the directory you are attempting to search in the path of `os.listdir`, and `open()`.

```
def choose_random_file():
    return random.choice(os.listdir("C:\landscapes\pics"))

def validate_randomness( random_file ):
    logfile = open('C:\landscapes\test.txt', 'r')
    loglist = logfile.readlines()
    logfile.close()
    found = False
    for line in loglist:        
        if str( random_file ) in line:
            print ("Found it")
            found = True
            # we found the file, now break out of the for loop
            break
    # Check if we found the file
    if found:
        # If we found the file name, then circle-back to pick another file
        random_file = choose_random_file()
        # Now validate that the new pick is in the test.txt file again
        validate_randomness( random_file )

    if not found:
        logfile = open('test.txt', 'a')
        logfile.write(str( random_file )+"\n")
        logfile.close()
        print ("Not Found!")

random_file = choose_random_file()
validate_randomness( random_file )
```

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.  Let me know if something doesn't work.

Comment: Ahhhh, Thank you so much! pure perfection!

Comment: @DanWest, great.  Go ahead and accept the answer if it worked for you.  Accepting it will ensure other people don't continue to think it is an open question and spending time trying to find an answer for you.